# use header Content-type text/css variable after include the style?

Tags: php

I have color.php and index.php:

color.php:

```
header("Content-type: text/css", true);
$color = "#ff0000";
echo"#div{$color}";
```

index.php

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='color.php' />
<?php
 echo"$color"; // want to use the stylesheet color php here
?>
```

but `$color` is empty.

any ideas how can I use the color.php `$color` value?

thank you friends!

Comment: Severside and client side are two different things.

Comment: does the php css file `color.php` reside in the same directory as whatever page it is in which you are including it?

Comment: I'm guessing you intended to `include` that color.php like `<?php include "color.php"; ?>` not `<link>`

Answer (score 2):

The browser makes an HTTP request to fetch the HTML document.

Then the link element causes the browser (unless the results are already in its cache) to make another HTTP request to fetch the stylesheet.

Each request (assuming both URLs are handled by PHP) runs a **different** PHP program which is not connected to the other (except, possibly, through session data).

The two different programs do not share variables between themselves.

Data could be shared between them (e.g. via a session or a database) but in that case, the stylesheet would load *second* so you would be trying to read the data (while generating the HTML document) before it had been stored.

If you want to write library files in PHP, then use a mechanism such as [`include`](http://php.net/include) to load them. You can't do it by going through the browser.

Comment: thank you for your answer! if I put color in a SESSION in color.php and read that SESSION in index.php can it work?

Comment: @RickJoe — No. As I stated in the second paragraph, the browser might not reload the stylesheet. As I stated in the penultimate paragraph, the two requests happen in the wrong order.